# Water planet where people live on organic rafts on the surface while the elites live in a city under the sea

Tags: story-identification, books

I checked this book out of a school library in the early 80's and it was really big and dusty then...it was about a people that lived on the surface of a water planet on living organic rafts. The elite undersea kingdom below, and a mysterious cylinder in space ...any help finding this book would be greatly appreciated
B

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169359/science-fiction-novel-or-novels-about-starship-that-becomes-a-god-colonizes-hos (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like one of the books in the [*Destination: Void*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination%3a_Void_universe#WorShip_novels) series by Frank Herbert and Bill Ransom. There are four books, [*Destination: Void*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination%3a_Void), [*The Jesus Incident*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jesus_Incident), [*The Lazarus Effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lazarus_Effect), and [*The Ascension Factor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ascension_Factor). My own personal guess is *The Lazarus Effect, as that seems to fit your question better. I seem to recall it had more of a class structure than the *Wikipedia* entry seems to imply.